# Force re-authentication using OAuthWebSecurity with Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

My website is using facebook as it's oauth provider.  Users will be able to buy things through my site so I want to force them to authenticate even if they already have an active session with facebook.

I found this [link in facebook's api documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/) that discusses reauthentication but I can't get it to work with my mvc app.  Anyone know if this is possible?

```
var extra = new Dictionary<string, object>();
extra.Add("auth_type", "reauthenticate");

OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
            appId: "**********",
            appSecret: "**********************",
            displayName: "",
            extraData: extra);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.  I had to create my own client instead of using the default one provided by `OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace Namespace.Helpers
{
    public class MyFacebookClient : DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client
    {
        private const string AuthorizationEP = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
        private const string TokenEP = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly string _appSecret;

        public MyFacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret)
            : base("facebook")
        {
            this._appId = appId;
            this._appSecret = appSecret;
        }


        protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
        {
            return new Uri(
                        AuthorizationEP
                        + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                        + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                        + "&scope=email,user_about_me"
                        + "&display=page"
                        + "&auth_type=reauthenticate"
                    );
        }

        protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken
            );
            dynamic data = Json.Decode(content);
            return new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {
                    "id",
                    data.id
                },
                {
                    "name",
                    data.name
                },
                {
                    "photo",
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/" + data.id + "/picture"
                },
                {
                    "email",
                    data.email
                }
            };
        }

        protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                TokenEP
                + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                + "&client_secret=" + this._appSecret
                + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                + "&code=" + authorizationCode
            );

            NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(content);
            if (nameValueCollection != null)
            {
                string result = nameValueCollection["access_token"];
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in AuthConfig.cs...

```
 OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(
                new MyFacebookClient(
                    appId: "xxxxxxxxxx", 
                    appSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                "facebook", null
            );
```

Comment: See my response if this answer doesn't work for you as it was correct at the time of writing but needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

As a note to those that happen upon this if your Facebook Authentication stopped working when v2.3 became the lowest version you have access to (non versioned calls get the lowest version an app has access to).   The API now returns JSON and not name value pairs so you have to update the QueryAccessToken method shown above by @Ben Tidman

Below is the updated method

```
protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                TokenEP
                + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                + "&client_secret=" + this._appSecret
                + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                + "&code=" + authorizationCode
            );

            dynamic json = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(content);
            if (json != null)
            {
                string result = json.access_token;
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one issue in using the MyFacebookClient implementation.
Probably someone tryin to implement it came across the error:

**The given key was not present in the dictionary**

attempting to call the ExternalLoginCallback method in ActionController.

The error raises when the method

```
OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

is called.

In order to get it working the method VerifyAuthentication has to be overridden.
In particular the

```
public virtual AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl);
```

overload of the abstract class OAuth2Client.

If you use the following:

```
 public override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl)
    {
        string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

        string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;
        //From this we need to remove code portion
        rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

        IDictionary<string, string> userData =    GetUserData(QueryAccessToken(returnPageUrl, code));

        if (userData == null)
            return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);


        AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, userData["id"], userData["name"], userData);
        userData.Remove("id");
        userData.Remove("name");
        return result;
    }
}
```

finally you get the method called in the right way and no excpetion is thrown.