# How to "rerequest" Facebook permissions using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone had any success with enabling Facebook's re-authentication feature using ASP.NET? (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication)

I tried using `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` but had no luck.

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
           appId: "APP-ID",
           appSecret: "SECRET");

var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
// Details ommitted for simplicity
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

I guess another option would be to use Facebook's Javascript SDK within ASP.NET but figured this Facebook re-authentication should be available out of the box with ASP.NET's `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` class?

Maybe I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we need to build a custom function to add the additional parameter - auth_type=reauthenticate that facebook re-authentication required. Please refer to [Force re-authentication using OAuthWebSecurity with Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063508/force-re-authentication-using-oauthwebsecurity-with-facebook). Quote key code section for your reference

```
 private const string AuthorizationEP = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";
        private const string TokenEP = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        private readonly string _appId;
        private readonly string _appSecret;

        public MyFacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret)
            : base("facebook")
        {
            this._appId = appId;
            this._appSecret = appSecret;
        }


        protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
        {
            return new Uri(
                        AuthorizationEP
                        + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                        + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                        + "&scope=email,user_about_me"
                        + "&display=page"
                        + "&auth_type=reauthenticate"
                    );
        }

        protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken
            );
            dynamic data = Json.Decode(content);
            return new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {
                    "id",
                    data.id
                },
                {
                    "name",
                    data.name
                },
                {
                    "photo",
                    "https://graph.facebook.com/" + data.id + "/picture"
                },
                {
                    "email",
                    data.email
                }
            };
        }

        protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string content = client.DownloadString(
                TokenEP
                + "?client_id=" + this._appId
                + "&client_secret=" + this._appSecret
                + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString())
                + "&code=" + authorizationCode
            );

            NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(content);
            if (nameValueCollection != null)
            {
                string result = nameValueCollection["access_token"];
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override FacebookAuthenticationProvider

the complete solution is here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41975557/341326